# Carrying Elapsed Time over to another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, elapsedtime

I have a small elapsed timer in my game and it works very well. However I am trying to figure out how to save the elapsed time when you die so I can carry it over to the Game Over Screen where the Score and High Score is displayed.

I tired a few things but none of them seem to work. I guess it's because the time is not being saved anywhere when the it's game over, but rather just reset to 00:00:00 when the game restarts.

I use two view Controllers for this timer. One is called Stopwatch the other code is in the GameScene. Here are the codes.

I wanna bring it into a label like for example:

```
    let timeLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Planer")
    timeLabel.text = "Time: \(savedTimer)"
    timeLabel.fontSize = 100
    timeLabel.fontColor = SKColor.white
    timeLabel.zPosition = 2
    timeLabel.position = CGPoint (x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height * 0.5)
    self.addChild(timeLabel)*/
```

Stopwatch.swift code

```
import Foundation

class Stopwatch {

private var startTime : Date?

var elapsedTime: TimeInterval {
    if let startTime = self.startTime {
        return -startTime.timeIntervalSinceNow
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}
var isRunning: Bool {
    return startTime != nil
}

func start() {
    startTime = Date()
}

func stop() {
    startTime = nil
}
}
```

And the code I got speed out through my Game Scene:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

private let formatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "mm:ss:SS"
    return formatter
}()

let watch = Stopwatch()

@IBOutlet weak var elapsedTimeLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func startButton(_ sender: Any) {
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateElapsedTimeLabel), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    watch.start()
}

@IBAction func stopButton(_ sender: Any) {
    watch.stop()
}

@objc func updateElapsedTimeLabel (timer : Timer) {
    if watch.isRunning {
        elapsedTimeLabel.text = formatter.string(from: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: watch.elapsedTime))
    } else {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand is that you're trying to save the `elapsedTime` of your `watch` after the user taps the stop button.  If that's the case, in your `stopButton` function you are calling `watch.stop()`, which in turn resets the `startTime = nil`.  So you might want to edit it like so:

```
// Create a new class variable to store the time
var savedTime: TimeInterval? = nil

@IBAction func stopButton(_ sender: Any) {
    savedTime = watch.elapsedTime
    //    Use the savedTime here to pass to the game over function
    watch.stop()
}
```

If you don't need to save the time in your `ViewController` class, you can move the `savedTime` variable to a local one in the `stopButton` function.

Comment: This kind works, but it's giving me a funky result. The label displays it as:

Time: Optional(10.526938915252686)

instead of -

Time: 00:10:52

Comment: @snapbackdev to get that `String` you need to convert the `TimeInterval` to `Date`.  You can use it like so: `elapsedTimeLabel.text = formatter.string(from: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: savedTime))`.  Let me know if this works :)

Comment: Perfect, not sure how I forgot that since I already used that one. Face Palm